# Evaluating the double integral in R^2.

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral

I saw a problem in Advanced Calculus course, it is required to evaluate the following integral:

$\iint x^2/y^2  dxdy$. The region is set bounded by the curves $x=2$, $y-x=0$ and $xy=1$.

My try:
I got the boundaries of integration by the curves by which region is defined, then I got the following:

∬_(1/2 1)^22▒〖x^2/y^2  dxdy=7/2〗

Comment: I don't understand the last line of your question. Can you detail it a bit more?

Comment: ignore it, it was my 1st try and it was wrong. The answer is claimed by having 1/x to be the lower bound and x the upper bound of y, then integrating over y first. Then you integrate the resulted function of x, and x is bounded between 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Draw a picture. The answer is  $\displaystyle \int_1^{2} \int_{1/x} ^{x} \frac  {x^{2}} {y^{2}} dydx=\frac  9   4$.

[Note that $xy=1$ and $y-x=0$ meet at $(1,1)$].

Comment: I made it, but I think miscalculated the integral, actually it is 9/4 not 5/6